# awk not showing right number of total field/column from my data

Tags: bash, awk

My sample data is below, shown using:
`cat -v sampel.txt` (to also show the hidden special chars)

[image]

If I dump my *sampel.txt* to excel, with delimiter `|`, the total fields/columns
are 75.
But when I try to count the total fields/columns, it shows only 12 fields:

```
awk -F "|@~" '{print NF}' sampel.txt
```

> 12

I need to get the 13th field's value `=53489958`, but when I type this:

```
awk -F "|@~" '{print $13}' sampel.txt
```

It doesn't show anything .

[image]

FYI, I work with IBM Aix Shell.

Any idea how to fix that? Is it because between field 12th and 13th , there's additional special (hidden) delimiter `^@` , means that in my sampel data there are multiple delimiters (from field 1 to 12, the delimiter is `|@~`, and then from field 13 there is additional delimiter `^@`).

How should I type the regex in the awk filtering then, in order to show the 13th field's value `=53489958`?

What should I type for the regex so the total fields/columns shown in my awk is 75 not 12 fields/columns?

Here is my raw data, copy and paste:

> 14027421900-23|@~14027421900|@~
>   00000000000000000000000000000000005002.|@~ |@~0|@~ |@~ |@~ |@~ |@~ |@~ |@~  |@~53489958|@~  |@~ |@~0         |@~ |@~ |@~ |@~ |@~
>   |@~2018-06-01|@~305111010001|@~1000|@~7212|@~4|@~11|@~6|@~ |@~ |@~3|@~
>   000000001847600.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ 000000000000000.00|@~ |@~ |@~617598679|@~ |@~379311|@~1  |@~BL |@~2082-[20180603191519244]Load Induk all 12THR  18.xls|@~P|@~
>   |@~2018-06-04|@~0         |@~2018-08-10|@~ |@~
>   |@~04062018|@~017318|@~017318|@~  |@~  |@~  |@~   |@~80079|@~022|@~
>   |@~0         |@~ |@~ 00000000000000000000000000000029157777.

Comment: Sample data as an image is not helping lost.  Cut and Past the data inn to your post.

Comment: Welcome to SO thank you for adding your efforts that what you have tried to fix your own problem. Please add samples in text format with code tags and let us know then.

Comment: @mas dani you need to use single delimiter instead of multiple, I would say, use `sed` change these delimiters to one delimiter say `|` or something you find suitable and then use `awk`. Otherwise pipe `awk -F<delimiter1>` to `awk -F<delimiter2>` to get/set your desired value.

Comment: Please post sample data. Do it like so: get some lines with `head -n5` and then run it through `xxd -p` and post the hex-es. Then someone can restore the original data exactly as they are with `xxd -p -r`. While the `^@` represents a null byte, are you sure your data aren't just null terminated? Or it looks like there are null terminated strings..

Comment: When posting sample input/output, indent each line by 4 spaces or use the editors `{}` button to format it properly. Make sure to include both the sample input AND the expected output given that input and make sure it's plain text, not images or links or anything else, so we have something we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: @PradyJord that's bad advice, you never need sed when you're using awk, nor do you need chains of multiple awks piped to each other. A single call to awk can handle using multiple delimiters just fine if that's really what the OP needs (which I'm not convinced of given what I see so far in the question).

Comment: @masdani - it may or  may not be the problem but those `^@`s in your file are probably NUL characters. Per POSIX, text files cannot contain NUL characters (many tools use C-strings internally to store the input they read and a C string is a set of chars terminated with NUL so one of those chars can't be NUL) and awk is a tool for processing text files. So you shouldn't be shocked if running awk on a non-text file doesn't work as you'd hoped. If you have or can get GNU awk, it'll be able to handle an input file that contains NULs. Otherwise you'll have to remove them with Excel or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton I stand corrected, lost a little touch I guess

Answer (score 1):

You Field Separator is wrong.

For only `|` as an separator, this is ok `-F'|'`  But when adding characters it will look at the `|` as an or and not work as you expect.  Try `-F'[|]@~'`.  It will give following separators: `|@~`

`-F'ab|zf'` will give `ab` or `zf` as separator.

Comment: There's a good chance this is correct for the OPs issue (I can't tell without some concrete input to look at) but in general having `|` as the first char of an ERE (or FS) is actually undefined behavior per POSIX so different awks (and other tools) will do different things with it. GNU awk, for example, will treat a `|` at the start of a FS as literal.

Answer (score 0):

As @EdMorton comments, the sample data seems to contain NUL characters.
One clue is that the `^@` patterns appear in the result of `cat -v` while
they are hidden in the cut and pasted text.

As the original AWK cannot handle NUL character, it may have stopped its
processing when it encountered the NUL character. That is why `NF` shows
only 12.

As an alternative, how about using `perl` which can handle binary data
including the NUL character? I'm not an `AIX` user, but
`perl` should be preinstalled in `AIX`. Then please try:

```
 perl -F'\|@~' -lane 'print $F[12]' sampel.txt
```

- `-F` option specifies the field separator (as that of `awk`).
  You need to escape the vertical bar because the field separator
  is the regex pattern and the vertical bar is otherwise interpreted as a metacharacter.
- `-lane` options tells `perl` to behave as `awk` in handling of newline,
  autosplit mode, etc.
- The array index is "12" becase the array index of `perl` starts from 0, not 1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @EdMorton. Yes you're right, it seems my awk version in  AIX can't parse NULL or ^@ right, as @Jotne suggest, i try with -F'[|]@~' but the result still the same , can't detect it. 
Voila, thanks again to @tshiono, i try your recipe with Perl and it WORKS ! Great.. Now I can sum all numerical fields in my raw data using one liner command with Perl like this for example :

```
perl -lan -F'\|@~' -e '$sum += $F[13]; print "Sum is $sum" if eof' sampel.txt
```

This command tells in my AIX shell to sum all field 13th from my source file 'sampel.txt', delimited with special chars '\|@'.